# Is my 'Tabbed App' keyboard issue caused by constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, tabbed

I have built a Tabbed App in Xcode (Swift 5). The app tabs (there are 4) work fine. Two currently load black pages and the other two load a web view (WKWebView). The web view works great, but when using a web based text field the keyboard barely appears.

I have tried removing and adjusting the constraints, but this failed as the issue is still present.

Here is the error output:

```
2019-06-11 20:17:51.999824+0100 TabbedApp[37023:4521411] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/james/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D1D0ACFE-2F91-40E6-B1EF-BF8FAB1DAC57/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-06-11 20:17:52.000649+0100 TabbedApp[37023:4521411] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-06-11 20:17:52.167789+0100 TabbedApp[37023:4521411] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003c738e0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.width == UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd40 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd90 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67200 H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe32f60]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe32f60]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c678e0 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe35590]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67930 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe35590]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f200 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f610 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f930 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f980 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f9d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa20 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa70 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c77b10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bac0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bb60 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe32f60]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-06-11 20:17:52.169351+0100 TabbedApp[37023:4521411] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003c738e0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.width == UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd40 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd90 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c678e0 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe35590]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67930 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe35590]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f200 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f610 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f930 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f980 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f9d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa20 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa70 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c77b10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bac0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bb60 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c67930 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe35590]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-06-11 20:17:52.170629+0100 TabbedApp[37023:4521411] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600003c738e0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.width == UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd40 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bd90 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcc6fe1e220.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f200 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f610 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f930 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f980 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe327d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f9d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe34d40]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa20 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe34f20]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6fa70 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x7fcc6fe358d0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c77b10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x7fcc6fe1dbb0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bac0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6bb60 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000026347e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcc6fe207f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c6f250 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcc6fe363f0'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcc6fe228b0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I expected the keyboard to appear fine like in other apps I have built utilising web view, but this is the first time I have had this issue. I'm hoping its something simple I may have missed. I'm not sure what else to try so any help would be greatly appreciated. I assume I have to give the keyboard priority, but I may be way off...

Comment: try pasting the error log here: [WTFAutoLayout](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/) and see if that gives you any hints on how to proceed

Comment: This is the greatest website ever! You are a legend, thank you. This will be very useful!